# Access query - how to show results if a FK for lookup is empty?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Imagine two SQL tables, MainTable and RefTable. MainTable has a FK reference to another table (say RefTable_ID). There are two entries in MainTable, one with MainTable.RefTable_ID set and the other with it null.

I want to show information from MainTable with some information based on the RefTable_ID foreign key from MainTable.

In Access, this is obviously trivial if MainTable.RefTable_ID has a value. But if MainTable.RefTable_ID is null a query does not show anything for that record but rather only shows results for records where MainTable.RefTable_ID is set.

What do I have to do in order to simply show empty results from the lookup for records where MainTable.RefTable_ID is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do a LEFT JOIN from [MainTable] to [RefTable]. Details here:

[Creating an outer join query in Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/creating-an-outer-join-query-in-access-HA001034555.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this makes me feel far more silly for not remembering than I want to admit. I'd chalk it up to being Monday but it's Wednesday. So... thank you :-)